# Accessing static methods using newly created $obj or using class Name

Tags: php, oop, static-methods

See the class definition below:
**I am currently using 5.3.9 version of PHP**

```
class A{
    static function ab(){
        echo "static function ab<br>";
    }

    public function xy(){
        echo "public function xy<br>";
    }
}

$obj =  new A();
$obj->ab();
A::ab();
```

Both functions call give the same output without any error

```
static function ab
static function ab
```

How it is possible that `static method` can also be called by class object?
Because `static method` only calls by using `class name only?!`

Now what is the difference between accessing these two ways to call `static method`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to php.net website

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method can).

A big difference is

> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static.

Refer to the page [php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) for more details

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are just echoing a simple string, there's no difference, if your method will be declared static or public, since static method can also be called with the object instance. As of PHP 5.5 an error will raise if you call your public method with a static way. However, the static method can be called with `classname::staticMethod()` so the page should only know about the class, but not really needs an instance of it.

The other deal is the method content. As I said, if you just echo a string, you don't need a static method for that. A static method is out of the object context. That means you cannot access properties or methods from the current object via $this

Comment: I removed `public` keyword from `static method`. Still it's giving same result.

Comment: What different result do you expect? Try in your static method to call `$this->xy()`

Comment: Yes. That I know that it will generate an error. But my concern was `calling static method` using an `instance of class`.

Comment: You have no problem to call a static method via instance of the class. The point is that you don't need it. You even don't need instance of this class. The official doc says you can access static methods via instance of the class, but you cannot access static properties same way

Comment: Ok. So static properties cannot be access through instance of class but static methods can be accessed.